# How to multiply a Mat and a scalar with EmguCV in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, emgucv

I've been trying to re-scale an Emgu.CV.Mat with depth 32F and value range [0,1] (a grayscale image) to range [0,255] in order to visualize it in a ImageBox object contained in a Visual Basic form, using the code line

```
ibSuave.Image = imgSuave * 255
```

However, Emgu.Cv.Mat doesn't have a Multiply method nor a defined * operator. I'd like to avoid converting the matrix to an Image. How else can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
CvInvoke.Multiply(mat, New ScalarArray(255), mat);
```

This will multiply each value in mat by 255 and stores result in mat again. I used EmguCV 3.4.1